# How to have a mailserver and a webserver on differents hosts?

Tags: dns, webserver, hosting, bind, mail-server

My company hired a web development service to a company, we have our own domain name, but this web development company does not provide an e-mail service.
So I want to know if there is any possibility to set up (with BIND9, Postfix, etc.) our own email server with the same domain on our own server, other than the hired for the web development company.

For example, our website will be hosted on Server1 with the domain name `www.exampledomainname.example`; emails will be hosted on Server2 to type addresses like `info@exampledomainname.example`

We have Bind9 and Postfix in our server, what other tool we need? (if it's possible to do)
How must I configure the email server to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to use different mail server, you should just set the correct MX records in your DNS settings. You could read more at http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/activate/mx_faq.html